# Stack Overflow SSL certificate appears invalid to my browser

Tags: support, ssl

I have been facing this issue for the past few days. Whenever I try to open Stack Overflow, it shows the connection is not private and when I click on the access unsafe button given down below, it opens without any CSS. All I can see is just the HTML skeleton of the site. I also did inspect the site page and checked security section. It's showing this error that the site is missing a valid certificate. How do I fix it?

[image: The address bar of the browser has the "https" part of the URL crossed out and a "Not Secure" message.]

[image: Security warning dialog states "Certificate is not valid".]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One reason for this type of problem is that your browser is still using any of the expired certificates, like 'DST Root CA X3' certificate.

So you can do one thing. Just check your certificate (by clicking on the left of the URL certificate can be viewed or you can do *Inspect* → *Security* → *View Certificate*), to see if it uses a 'DST Root CA X3' type certificate. Then you have to import a new 'ISRG Root X1' certificate.

One can do this easily by following this. Visit *[How to install ISRG Root certificate on your machine](https://docs.sembark.com/blog/2021/10/04/install-letsencrypt-root-certificate-isrg-root-x1/)*. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score -6):

Are you under a proxy?  Normally they create a SSL certificate clone on the fly to access the data for monitoring purposes, and your browser won't trust it. It is necessary to add the company proxy certs to the trusted browser certs list.

If you are connected directly without a proxy, you probably have a local proxy installed on your machine.  Normally a virus does it.